# Android: How to notify activity of an other activities finish()

Tags: android, events, android-activity, activity-finish

I do have a activity, which I don't have access to (we're working at an AIR ANE). From this activity, the one we're working on is triggered, but we can't use onActivityResult, as we don't have access to the calling activity. How can I work around this? If I close the second activity via finish(), it's to late to send an event. If I sent it before, the underlaying activity is still paused, as I've understood. I thought about using an Handler with a postDelayed, but I think, the timing will make this approach messy. Is there something like didFinish(), that's called once the next activity has already resumed?

Any thoughts appreciated!
Thnx, Marcus

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The easiest way would be to [send a broadcast](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#sendBroadcast%28android.content.Intent%29) before calling `finish()`  and to register a [`BroadcastReceiver`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html) where you want to be notified.

Comment: wouldn't that require access, I don't have? basically, I can send a notification to the extension context, which will forward it, that's it 8/ any suggestions?

Comment: The way I see it, to send the broadcast before finish isn't my problem, but to register for the broadcast in the original activity, that started the later one?

Comment: It is true that the other Activity will be paused when finish() is called and that your receiver would be unregistered. However you can either register your receiver in a Service or in your Application subclass which is always alive.

Comment: I'm currently working on a different scenario. I instantiate a new service, which then starts the activity. Now I'got to figure out how to communicate from the activity back to the service. As the service is no activity, it should not block the original one. So, I might be able to send the much needed event from there. Any idea how to communicate back TO the service FROM the activity, before the activities' finish()?

Comment: If you register your BroadcastReceiver in your service and send a broadcast from your activity before finish() you'll be just fine.

Comment: In my activity, I call finish() and send the broadcast in onDestroy. thnx

Comment: It's better to give us a live example.  Android guide doesn't seem to easy understand.

Answer (score 0):

You can use toast,alert or even broadcast receiver before calling finish();